# Can i upload build on app store with only 4 inch launch image in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone

Can i upload build on app store with only 4 inch launch image in iOS 9? Means my app is working but i am putting only 4 inch launch screen, I am not putting launch images for 4.7 and 5.5 inch devices.Does apple allows this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can upload app on app store with 4 inch launch image.

Answer (score 2):

You can, but i do not recommend it, because your 4.7 and 5.5 inch users will get an upscaled version of your 4 inch optimized app, with is bad.

Instead i recommend using a LaunchScreen xib or storyboard and proper use of autolayout in your storyboards.

Note: every launch screen you support will need App Store images also.
That will multiply the time of App Store screen creations.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not mentioned anywhere that launch images above 4 inch device size is mandatory until we follow the sizes mentioned at [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2) Apple page.

According to my view, it would be always better to provide support of 4.4 and 5.7 inch launch image support because somewhere Apple has mentioned below in **What's new in iOS 8**:

> **Supporting New Screen Scales :**
>   The iPhone 6 Plus uses a new Retina HD display with a very high DPI screen. To support this resolution, iPhone 6 Plus creates a UIScreen object with a screen size of 414 x 736 points and a screen scale of 3.0 (1242 x 2208 pixels). After the contents of the screen are rendered, UIKit samples this content down to fit the actual screen dimensions of 1080 x 1920. To support this rendering behavior, include new artwork designed for the new 3x screen scale. In Xcode 6, asset catalogs can include images at 1x, 2x, and 3x sizes; simply add the new image assets and iOS will choose the correct assets when running on an iPhone 6 Plus. The image loading behavior in iOS also recognizes an @3x suffix

I would recommend to include launch images for 4.4 and 5.7 images as well to avoid Apple rejection.

Comment: According to now, you wont get rejected if you only support 4 inch devices. 4 inch is a must, others are just recommended.